# How can I change connection strings for database in my web.config that have database name based on Login_User table from LOGIN database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

Currently I have one connection string in my `web.config` that has `database: NORTHWIND_HR` - like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=NORTHWIND_HR;User ID=userName;Password=PASS" />
</connectionStrings>`
```

I have many grids, table, dropdown, based on that connection string in my web applications. So all the controls that require something from the database use `SqlDataSource` and the same connection string.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConectionString %>" 
     ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT ... ">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Up until now I only needed one connection string since I had only one database but this has changed since I want different users group to login to different database based on departments for which I have crated one login database that have user and password and database names.

> **NOTE**: these are demo structures for explaining my requirements only.

[image: LOGIN database]

As per requirement’s I will have to create different **database (approx 100000)** dynamically with same schema and table.

[image: Database with same schema and table]

This application is totally based on .aspx file, I had don’t touch the code behind .aspx.cs file because as per my requirements, the website will be ALWAYS ON (like SQL Server 2014 always on features), and the website and database will be modified for 2 years in real time on server. I don’t want to stop the website for upload new .dll file, that’s why I used `SqlDataSource`.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=NORTHWIND_HR;User ID=userName;Password=PASS" />
</connectionStrings>`
```

How can I change connection strings `DATABASE` in my `web.config` that have database based on `Login_User` table from LOGIN database?

Or is there any other technique to define connection strings at any other location?

Or is there any other technique?

Comment: Add a second connection string. There is nothing magical here. It is XML so you can have as many connection strings as you want. Just make sure the name is unique for each of them.

Comment: This is weird that a user from another department should use a different database. are you separating your data into different databases for each department?

Comment: I have uploaded the image to explain my requirement, because of my 1 reputation I can not make it visible. If you can edit please make my image visible.

Comment: @marc_s  can you please make image visible

Comment: You really shouldn't use separate databases for this sort of thing. Just use one database and filter results by department. Multiple databases is much harder to manage and you should only do it with good reason.

Comment: Note also that you appear to be storing passwords in plaintext in your database. Don't do that! You should be one-way hashing and salting the passwords.

Comment: So you're going to have over 100000 databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I) If you have access to the details of the currently logged in user in your asp code, the easiest solution would be:

1) Add the connection strings in the web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConectionString_IT" connectionString="Data source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=NORTHWIND_IT;User ID=userName;Password=PASS" />
    <add name="MyConectionString_HR" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=NORTHWIND_HR;User ID=userName;Password=PASS" />
</connectionStrings>
```

2) In the ASP code, check using an [IF statement](http://www.tizag.com/aspTutorial/aspIfStatement.php) to see what DATABASE the user has assigned and create the control element based on that. Something like:

```
<% IF user.Database = "NORTHWIND_IT" Then
    <asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConectionString_IT %>" 
         ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         SelectCommand="SELECT ... ">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    ELSE

    <asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConectionString_HR %>" 
         ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         SelectCommand="SELECT ... ">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    END IF
    %>
```

II) If the username, password and data source will be the same for all the databases, you can use string format to replace the initial catalog with the database you want.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConectionString" connectionString="Data source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog={0};User ID=userName;Password=PASS" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and your ASP code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
     ConnectionString="<%$ String.Format(ConnectionStrings:MyConectionString, user.Database) %>" 
     ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT ... ">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Using an if/else block and repeating your SqlDataSource declarations is a very poor idea. Now you've got duplicated markup, and anytime you add/remove a department you need to change the code.

Comment: @Ovidiu Chis I guess your second statement is good. `ConnectionString="<%$ String.Format(ConnectionStrings:MyConectionString, user.Database) %>"` But how can I change the `user.Database`. Can you explain it.

Comment: @Surya, the problem is that I can see only a small part of your code. I'm not sure what you are doing in your application. I assume that an user (A@Gmail.com) logs in. When he logs in successfully, you should create an object (i.e. "user") and store the data you need there (his phone number, his email, the Database). Can you explain in short the workflow you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @OvidiuChis Exactly you are correct. When user login, the login page will access the `User_login` table form `Login` database and store `Database` column value in `User.Database` object. I guess the `User.Database` object will be stored in `SESSION VARIABLE`. But @OvidiuChis my main concern is that how accurate it will work. **If there are thousands of users form different database(e.g. 500 Database)**, then Is there any chance for miss-match or wrong transaction or any thing else like application error.

Comment: @Surya as long as you retrieve the data correctly and name your databases accordingly there shouldn't be a mismatch. Your data source will take the name of the database contained in the User.Database  variable - that's all. What you need to be concerned probably is how you store the sensitive data and how easily it is accessible to be changed by the end user. (i.e. if you store it in a cookie and the application uses it, the user can change the name of the database) - so be careful. However, this is an entirely different story.

Answer (score 0):

Your app would need 1 connection string per database, and when you attempt to establish the connection to the database pull the correct connection string per file.  So the data access layer switches permission by role.  Ideally, you'd have to have a master database for the users with the appropriate database they should connect to.

Rather than having database separation, I would recommend having the separation defined within the application (one database, with application role security defined within the application).  There is complexity, sure, but it will be easier to maintain over time.

Comment: As per my requirement, it is necessary to separate the database. I could make this possible in ASP.NET MVC, but for real time changes on running server it will stop my site for republish it for many times that I don't want to do. That's why I chose ASP.NET WebForm Application through `SqlDataSource` but only I have **connection string** issue.